# Average columns based on other column value and number of rows in R

Tags: r, average

I'm using R and am trying to create a new dataframe of averaged results from another dataframe based on the values in Column A. To demonstrate my goal here is some data:

```
set.seed(1981)
df <- data.frame(A = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100),
B=round(runif(100), digits=4), 
C=sample(1:1000, 100, replace=TRUE))
head(df, 30)

A   B       C
0   0.6739  459
1   0.5466  178
0   0.154   193
0   0.41    206
1   0.7526  791
1   0.3104  679
1   0.739   434
1   0.421   171
0   0.3653  577
1   0.4035  739
0   0.8796  147
0   0.9138  37
0   0.7257  350
1   0.2125  779
0   0.1502  495
1   0.2972  504
0   0.2406  245
1   0.0325  613
0   0.8642  539
1   0.1096  630
1   0.2113  363
1   0.277   974
0   0.0485  755
1   0.0553  412
0   0.509   24
0   0.2934  795
0   0.0725  413
0   0.8723  606
0   0.3192  591
1   0.5557  177
```

I need to reduce the size of the data by calculating the average value for column B and column C for as many rows as the value in Column A stays consecutively the same, up to a maximum of 3 rows. If value A remains either 1, or 0 for more than 3 rows it would roll over into the next row in the new dataframe as you can see below.

The new dataframe requires the following columns:

```
Value of A  B.Av         C.Av   No. of rows used
0           0.6739       459            1
1           0.5466       178            1
0           0.282        199.5          2
1           0.600666667  634.6666667    3
1           0.421        171            1
0           0.3653       577            1
1           0.4035       739            1
0           0.8397       178            3
1           0.2125       779            1
0           0.1502       495            1
1           0.2972       504            1
0           0.2406       245            1
1           0.0325       613            1
0           0.8642       539            1
1           0.1993       655.6666667    3
0           0.0485       755            1
1           0.0553       412            1
0           0.291633333  410.6666667    3
0           0.59575      598.5          2
1           0.5557       177            1
```

I haven't managed to find another similar scenario to mine whilst searching Stack Overflow so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base-R solution:

```
## define a function to split the run-length if greater than 3
split.3 <- function(l,v) {
  o <- c(values=v,lengths=min(l,3)) 
  while(l > 3) {
    l <- l - 3
    o <- rbind(o,c(values=v,lengths=min(l,3)))
  } 
  return(o)
}

## compute the run-length encoding of column A
rl <- rle(df$A)

## apply split.3 to the run-length encoding
## the first column of vl are the values of column A
## the second column of vl are the corresponding run-length limited to 3
vl <- do.call(rbind,mapply(split.3,rl$lengths,rl$values))

## compute the begin and end row indices of df for each value of A to average
fin <- cumsum(vl[,2])
beg <- fin - vl[,2] + 1

## compute the averages
out <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(beg), function(i) data.frame(`Value of A`=vl[i,1],
                                                                  B.Av=mean(df$B[beg[i]:fin[i]]),
                                                                  C.Av=mean(df$C[beg[i]:fin[i]]),
                                                                  `No. of rows used`=fin[i]-beg[i]+1)))
##   Value.of.A      B.Av     C.Av No..of.rows.used
##1           0 0.6739000 459.0000                1
##2           1 0.5466000 178.0000                1
##3           0 0.2820000 199.5000                2
##4           1 0.6006667 634.6667                3
##5           1 0.4210000 171.0000                1
##6           0 0.3653000 577.0000                1
##7           1 0.4035000 739.0000                1
##8           0 0.8397000 178.0000                3
##9           1 0.2125000 779.0000                1
##10          0 0.1502000 495.0000                1
##11          1 0.2972000 504.0000                1
##12          0 0.2406000 245.0000                1
##13          1 0.0325000 613.0000                1
##14          0 0.8642000 539.0000                1
##15          1 0.1993000 655.6667                3
##16          0 0.0485000 755.0000                1
##17          1 0.0553000 412.0000                1
##18          0 0.2916333 410.6667                3
##19          0 0.5957500 598.5000                2
##20          1 0.5557000 177.0000                1
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to apply this to my data just as needed. I've not seen the 'rle' function before so thank you for bringing it to my attention. This will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
# create two group variables, consecutive A and for each consecutive A every three rows
(df[,rleid := rleid(A)][, threeWindow := ((1:.N) - 1) %/% 3, rleid]

# calculate the average of the columns grouped by the above two variables
   [, c(.N, lapply(.SD, mean)), .(rleid, threeWindow)]

# drop group variables
   [, `:=`(rleid = NULL, threeWindow = NULL)][])

 #   N A         B        C
 #1: 1 0 0.6739000 459.0000
 #2: 1 1 0.5466000 178.0000
 #3: 2 0 0.2820000 199.5000
 #4: 3 1 0.6006667 634.6667
 #5: 1 1 0.4210000 171.0000
 #6: 1 0 0.3653000 577.0000
 #7: 1 1 0.4035000 739.0000
 #8: 3 0 0.8397000 178.0000
 #9: 1 1 0.2125000 779.0000
#10: 1 0 0.1502000 495.0000
#11: 1 1 0.2972000 504.0000
#12: 1 0 0.2406000 245.0000
#13: 1 1 0.0325000 613.0000
#14: 1 0 0.8642000 539.0000
#15: 3 1 0.1993000 655.6667
#16: 1 0 0.0485000 755.0000
#17: 1 1 0.0553000 412.0000
#18: 3 0 0.2916333 410.6667
#19: 2 0 0.5957500 598.5000
#20: 1 1 0.5557000 177.0000
```